# MongoDB - join collections, filter and sort

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections, "business" and "review":

```
// business row example
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ddbc3c1a94f7aac8d179b7c"),
    "business_id" : "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA",
    "full_address" : "4840 E Indian School Rd\nSte 101\nPhoenix, AZ 85018",
    "hours" : {
        "Tuesday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Friday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Monday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Wednesday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        },
        "Thursday" : {
            "close" : "17:00",
            "open" : "08:00"
        }
    },
    "open" : true,
    "categories" : [ 
        "Doctors", 
        "Health & Medical"
    ],
    "city" : "Phoenix",
    "review_count" : 7,
    "name" : "Eric Goldberg, MD",
    "neighborhoods" : [],
    "longitude" : -111.983758,
    "state" : "AZ",
    "stars" : 3.5,
    "latitude" : 33.499313,
    "attributes" : {
        "By Appointment Only" : true
    },
    "type" : "business"
}
```

```
// review example
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ddbc3ea9d4415aa1e6696ae"),
    "votes" : {
        "funny" : 0,
        "useful" : 0,
        "cool" : 0
    },
    "user_id" : "KBLW4wJA_fwoWmMhiHRVOA",
    "review_id" : "dNocEAyUucjT371NNND41Q",
    "stars" : 4,
    "date" : "2012-03-02",
    "text" : "Been going to Dr. Goldberg for over 10 years. I think I was one of his 1st patients when he started at MHMG. He's been great over the years and is really all about the big picture. It is because of him, not my now former gyn Dr. Markoff, that I found out I have fibroids. He explores all options with you and is very patient and understanding. He doesn't judge and asks all the right questions. Very thorough and wants to be kept in the loop on every aspect of your medical health and your life.",
    "type" : "review",
    "business_id" : "vcNAWiLM4dR7D2nwwJ7nCA"
}
```

I want to count how many stars on average each business got and sort descending by that value. So far I've got:

```
db.getCollection('review')
.aggregate
([
{
    $group:
    {
        _id: "$business_id",
        avgStars: {$avg: "$stars"}
    }
},
{
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "business",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "business_id",
        as: "business_data"
    }
},
{$unwind: "$business_data"},
{$project: {"name": "$business_data.name", "avgStars": "$avgStars"}},
//{$sort: {avgStars: -1}}
])
```

Without the commented part it works - gets me list of (_id, name, avgStars). When I uncomment the `$sort` function, it stops working - Robo3T processes infinitely. Collection is only 50 elements. Why does sorting not work?

Comment: Does sort work if it is a second stage (before lookup)?

Comment: @AlexBlex yes, but it's... weird. I did only `$group` and `$sort`, and after sorting all `avgStars` fields have value 5.0

Comment: A guess your collections are slightly bigger than 50 elements. What numbers `.count()`  gives you for both?

Comment: @AlexBlex yeah, you are right! Those collections are actually a bit over 1 milion elements each... Robo3T was so "kind" to show 50 elements without any indication that there are more (and with a few misleading indications...). So no wonder that sorting with other operations takes so long, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

take this query as reference, Put order of $sort before projection stage...

```
db.review.aggregate([ { 
                         $group: { 
                                   _id:"$business_id", 
                                    avgStars: { $avg:"$stars" } 
                                 } 
                      }, 
                      { 
                         $lookup:{ 
                                   from:"business", 
                                   localField:"_id", 
                                   foreignField:"business_id", 
                                   as:"business_data" 
                                 }  
                     }, 
                     { 
                        $unwind:"$business_data" 
                     },
                     { 
                         $sort :{ "avgStars":-1 }  
                     }, 
                     { 
                         $project:{ 
                              "name":"$business_data.name", 
                              "avgStars":"$avgStars" 
                         } 
                     } 
           ])
```

Comment: With your code it freezes on sort (I checked it with `$project` commented out)